Nuxt 3 Multiple Nested Dynamic Routes
I have this directory structure in Nuxt 3.

If I visited the directory structure above the nuxt routes works like this;
/ = pages/index.vue
/fruits/ = pages/[category]/index.vue
/fruits/apple/ = pages/[category]/[slug].vue
/fruits/apple/a-delicious-fuji-apple = pages/[category]/[sub-category]/[slug].vue
/fruits/a-healthy-fruit = pages/[category]/[slug].vue
But I have a problem rendering the
/fruits/apple/
Instead of this
/fruits/apple/ = pages/[category]/[slug].vue
I want to this
/fruits/apple/ = pages/[category]/[sub-category]/index.vue
I already add the [sub-category].vue in the [category] but still not working.
I also define it in nuxt config but still not working.

Is the dynamic slug, and the dynamic sub-category under the dynamic category?

no. A category has an index for listing the items and a slug to view the items in the category. same in the sub-category.

So, it is going to be a dynamic category, and then inside the dynamic category folder there is a dynamic slug, correct? You can't use dynamic slug and dynamic sub category together under the dynamic category. It can be [category]->[sub-category]->[slug]
